# How to cast a nested array in Glue job

Tags: arrays, amazon-web-services, schema, aws-glue

I have this schema in the AWS Glue job:

```
root
    |-- SortedLenders: array
    |    |-- element: struct
    |    |    |-- LenderID: string
    |    |    |-- MaxProfit: string
    |-- FilteredOutDecisions: array
    |    |-- element: struct
    |    |    |-- ApprovedAmount: string
    |    |    |-- Reasons: array
    |    |    |    |-- element: int
```

I can cast a string of FilteredOutDecisions.ApprovedAmount to double using resolveChoice() method:

```
test.resolveChoice(specs=[('FilteredOutDecisions[].ApprovedAmount', 'cast:double')])
```

But I am wondering how to cast **FilteredOutDecisions.Reasons** to string. Could anyone help me with this out?
Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and it worked:
I converted Glue dynamicFrame to Spark dataFrame: `df=dyf.toDF()`, and applied the below the code to a converted dataframe:

```
import pyspark.sql from functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types from StructType, StructField, ArrayType, StringType

df= df.withColumn('FilteredOutDecisions', F.col('FilteredOutDecisions').cast(ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField("ApprovalStatus", StringType()),
            StructField("Reasons", ArrayType(StringType()))
        ]))))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use Spark SQL StructType & StructField classes. Instead, glue purpose build transformations. which makes us to define schema to the DF and creating complex nested schema, enables casting to a particular type.

Convert your glue dynamic frame to spark df, then, do use above mentioned classes.

Comment: I did so already and it worked. Anyway, thank you for your answer!